Windows GUI program to easily sync local directories
I'm looking for a Windows GUI program (preferably open source and/or free) to easily sync the contents of two USB-connected external hard drives, or a local directory with an external drive. Much to my surprise, this has proven to be much more difficult than it looks.
Synkron worked very well, but all of a sudden it stopped working (the main window does not open). I've decided to abandon it anyway, as a new version has not been released since 2011.
FreeFileSync does not see all directories on one hard disk, for some reason.
rsync is command-line only.
Grsync is advertised on Wikipedia as existing also for Windows platforms but I was unable to find a Windows version.
Syncthing runs as a local service and is operated via a web GUI. Too bloated and complicated.

I use Beyond Compare
Blurb from website

Beyond Compare is the popular choice for data comparison.  Compare folders, text files, images, and tables.  Review differences efficiently and merge changes with confidence.

Note, I am not associated with it, but have been using it for over a decade. I use it manually to sync files between hard disk with NAS box, HD with USB stick, HD with USB drive, and HD with my website using FTP (built into it).
But you can script things as well.  I have never used scripting in it.
It is not free, it has free trial version.  But it is cheap to buy, there are no recurring fees.

I'm surprised you had an issue with the open source FreeFileSync.  It ticks all your requirement/preference boxes, plus it's cross-platform (Linux and Windows).  I've used it on Linux and Windows, and I've never encountered a significant issue with it.  I encourage you to report the issue you encountered here.
In lieu of FreeFileSync, I will reluctantly recommend SyncBackFree by 2BrightSparks.  Here's how it ticks your requirement/preference boxes:
[x] Windows GUI program.
[x] Preferably open source and/or free: It's free (of cost), but not open source.
[x] Easily sync the contents of two USB-connected external hard drives.
[x] Easily sync a local directory with an external drive.
The big disadvantage, as compared to FreeFileSync is that its the source code is not open to inspection or bug fixing.  The notable advantage, as compared to FreeFileSync, is that it supports a dark theme, which FreeFileSync still does not.  Another downside to FreeFileSync is that it automatically tries to connect to an update server (a big no-no), and the current version has no way to disable that functionality.  Fortunately, it works if you block that connection via a firewall (and I imagine people will not be happy if that ever changes).
I've used both applications.  I do consider FreeFileSync to be superior.  I chose to stop using SyncBack software when I found numerous bugs.  It became apparent that their QA team, if they had one, was not doing a good enough job.  2BrightSparks wasn't willing to compensate me for my time when I offered to help improve the quality of their software, so I switched to more reliable tools.  Thus, I typically recommend FreeFileSync (or commercial software) over any of the SyncBack products from 2BrightSparks.  But because you had an issue with FreeFileSync, and SyncBackFree meets your requirements, you may want to see if you have success with it.

I've solved my problem by running the PortableApps version of Synkron.  This one works.
I'm still interested in hearing about other alternatives, since apparently there isn't much software that does this properly.

I'm not sure if it's up to your requirements, but FileZilla offers directory syncing, although you have to do so manually (I think there's probably some way to automate it with a script)
I think it's originally intended for Syncing with remote directories (over FTP or similar), but it should work with local directories and disks as well.
You can find the official guide on syncing directories at https://filezillapro.com/docs/v3/advanced/file-synchronization/
